# "Cannot find executable for CFBundle" while loading bundle with resources only

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nsbundle

I'm using an `NSBundle` to load localization files into my iOS app.

Since I'm building with Xcode 11 everything is still working as expected, but I get a warning each time I read localizations from that bundle:

```
Cannot find executable for CFBundle [...] (not loaded)
```

The thing is there is no executable in the bundle. It contains nothing but the localization files and an `Info.plist` which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>BNDL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The bundle is loaded with

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
if (![bundle isLoaded]) {
    [bundle load];
}
```

and the localization read with

```
NSString *string = [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:defaultValue table:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `- load` from `NSBundle` is only there to load executables from a bundle. 
From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1415927-load?language=objc):

> Dynamically loads the bundle’s executable code into a running program, if the code has not already been loaded.

For bundles with only resources it's not necessary to call `- load`.